# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored on stored procedure "with" clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Hi I'm currently working with oracle that will give me my required output.
I able to make the query, but when I'm putting it in stored procedure it gives me error of
`Error(11,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored` and
`Error(15,20): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression`

Here's  my query not in procedure:

```
with 
t1  as (
select * from vw_break_time_doublebreak 
/* where clause that satisfies your query */
where date_time >= date '2020-01-01' and date_time < date '2020-02-01'
)
,t2 as (
select shift, trunc(min(min(date_time)) over (), 'mm') mn, last_day(max(max(date_time)) over ()) mx 
from t1
group by shift
)
,t3 as (
select shift, mn + level - 1 dateshift from t2
connect by mn + level - 1  <= mx
and prior shift = shift
and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
SELECT t3.shift, t3.dateshift AS date_time, count (CNT) AS COUNT
    FROM t3 
    left join 
    vw_break_time_doublebreak db
    on (t3.shift = db.shift and t3.dateshift = TRUNC (db.date_time))
GROUP BY t3.shift, dateshift
ORDER BY t3.shift, dateshift;
```

But when I put it on stored procedure it has error:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           sp_bt_getcountDblBreakbyshift (
   in_date      IN       VARCHAR2,
   in_date_end  IN       VARCHAR2,
   in_pagenum   IN       INT,
   p_rec        OUT      sys_refcursor
)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN p_rec FOR

with   <-------Error here
t1  as (
select * from vw_break_time_doublebreak 
/* where clause that satisfies your query */
where date_time >= date in_date and date_time < date in_date_end <------ error here
)
,t2 as (
select shift, trunc(min(min(date_time)) over (), 'mm') mn, last_day(max(max(date_time)) over ()) mx 
from t1
group by shift
)
,t3 as (
select shift, mn + level - 1 dateshift from t2
connect by mn + level - 1  <= mx
and prior shift = shift
and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
SELECT t3.shift, t3.dateshift AS date_time, count (CNT) AS COUNT
    FROM t3 
    left join 
    vw_break_time_doublebreak db
    on (t3.shift = db.shift and t3.dateshift = TRUNC (db.date_time))
GROUP BY t3.shift, dateshift
ORDER BY t3.shift, dateshift;
END;
```

I'm just new in oracle and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you can not use like this `date in_date` but like `date'2020-04-03'` as a literal example. So, remove the preceding part `date` within the procedure. Keep **only** `in_date` while use the literal during the invocation.

Comment: Does it fail during compilation, or execution? Because, it looks OK. If it is *during execution*, did you provide all parameters? If I were you, and if DATE_TIME column's datatype is DATE, I'd pass DATE parameters, not strings (VARCHAR2).

Comment: it does fail during compilation when i try to put it on stored procedure

Comment: Can you try to strip the sql down to a minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) must actually be a literal, not a variable; as a simpler example shows:

```
select date '2020-03-22' from dual;

DATE'2020-
----------
2020-03-22

var str varchar2(10);
exec :str := '2020-03-22';
select date :str from dual;

ORA-00936: missing expression
```

So you cannot do:

```
date in_date
```

You could change that to:

```
to_date(in_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

but the better thing to do is change your parameters to expect dates rather than strings, and make the client responsible for providing data of the correct type:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           sp_bt_getcountDblBreakbyshift (
   in_date      IN       DATE,
   in_date_end  IN       DATE,
   in_pagenum   IN       INT,
   p_rec        OUT      sys_refcursor
)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN p_rec FOR

with
t1  as (
select * from vw_break_time_doublebreak 
/* where clause that satisfies your query */
where date_time >= in_date and date_time < in_date_end
)
,t2 as (
select shift, trunc(min(min(date_time)) over (), 'mm') mn, last_day(max(max(date_time)) over ()) mx 
from t1
group by shift
)
,t3 as (
select shift, mn + level - 1 dateshift from t2
connect by mn + level - 1  <= mx
and prior shift = shift
and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
SELECT t3.shift, t3.dateshift AS date_time, count (CNT) AS COUNT
    FROM t3 
    left join 
    vw_break_time_doublebreak db
    on (t3.shift = db.shift and t3.dateshift = TRUNC (db.date_time))
GROUP BY t3.shift, dateshift
ORDER BY t3.shift, dateshift;
END;
/
```

Comment: yes that would answer the second error but how about the with clause? in store procedure?

Comment: It address both errors - but there is actually only one, the entire statement that happens to start with `with` is ignored because of the invalid date literal further down. The ORA-00936 is the important part; the statement being ignored is a consequence of that. There is nothing wrong with using a `with` clause in PL/SQL, or in a cursor loop as you have it.